# have to invoke (Thread.__init__) in my overridden constructor, but why?

Tags: python

i saw this phrase in python 2.6 man:

```
class threading.Thread(group=None, target=None, name=None, args=(), kwargs={}) 
.
.
.
```

If the subclass overrides the constructor, it must make sure to invoke the base class constructor (`Thread.__init__()`) before doing anything else to the thread.
i just wanna know why?

Answer (score 3):

Because `Thread.__init__` sets some internal variables which will be undefined if you omit the call.  In general, it is a good practice to invoke super constructor in all cases unless there is a strong reason to not do it.

Answer (score 2):

If you want to know "exactly what, in detail, does the superclass's `__init__` do for me", you can always study [the sources](http://svn.python.org/view/python/trunk/Lib/threading.py?revision=79817&view=markup) and see, e.g., ...:

```
    self.__target = target
    self.__name = str(name or _newname())
    self.__args = args
    self.__kwargs = kwargs
    self.__daemonic = self._set_daemon()
    self.__ident = None
    self.__started = Event()
    self.__stopped = False
    self.__block = Condition(Lock())
    self.__initialized = True
```

the exact set of super-private variables being initialized may of course vary from one revision of python to the next, but obviously there are always going to be *some* such variables and/or other initialization stuff performed in the base class's `__init__`.  You only need to know all details for your own instruction (you should "respect" abstraction layers you choose to program on, but, if you're a wise and experienced developer, the better you *understand* what those abstraction layers are wisely hiding, the more you'll respect them;-).

In general, the rule should always be for each `__init__` to invoke the superclass's, except only very specific cases (such as "transparent mixin classes" -- and if you don't know what they are, you most likely don't *need* to know).  The general rule will always be "that superclass initialization may or may not be important in this specific release, but it will never hurt and will often be necessary and/or helpful"!-)